# Define max and minimum series for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a line chart as the picture below.  The max and min values in my data are 410 and 290 for the peakflow series (the chart's visible range is something like 0 and 500 which is a bit pointless as there is no data below 290 or above 410).  There are no zero values but there are empty values in the peakflow data.

Is there a way to define the chart's max and min values for the peakflow (left) vertical series?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the chart's max and min values for the peakflow (left) vertical series by editing your chart:

- `Chart` > `Edit the chart` > `Customize` > `Vertical axis`

[image]

**Keep in mind**:
This action will change the look of your chart.
The look also depends on your second values (`Inhalor`). Check or uncheck the `Allow bounds to hide data` for different results.

(*If you still have issues please share a test sheet*.)

Comment: did I really miss that?  I looked and looked.  Thank you!

Comment: "_did I really miss that?_" Too much caffeine. :)

Answer (score 7):

## Workaround for when the *Min* and *Max* fields do not appear:

It seems Google Sheets hides the *Min* and *Max* fields if the values are formatted as dates, date times, durations, or currencies. Here is the workaround:

1. First, format all the relevant cells as plain numbers by clicking *Format*, *Number*, *Number*.
2. Then, right-click on the chart and click "Edit chart". Then click "Customise".
3. Under *vertical axis* or *horizontal axis*, you should find the *Min* and *Max* fields:

[image: srceenshot]

4. Now, if you want to return to the original formatting of the cells, you can. The minimum and maximum values will continue to apply.